# How pass API Key to the Azure Machine Learning Web service using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to connect to Azure Machine Learning Web service using `Invoke-WebRequest` in PowerShell. after bellow command I will get an error that **"Request is unauthorized to access 
resource."**:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Method POST -Body $body
```

As I know, you can connect to a Machine Learning Web service using any programming language that **supports HTTP request and response**. read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/consume-web-services#connect).

Seems I need to pass `API Key` with my request. I have tried this two types of command, but the error was same:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Method POST -Body $body -Headers @{'apikey' = $API_key}
```

and

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Method POST -Body $body -Header @{ "X-ApiKey" = $API_key }
```

Can you please guide me how I can pass `API Key` to the Azure Machine Learning Web service using PowerShell?

Comment: Have you read their documentation?

Comment: If you look at that doc you linked: `-Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer " + $apiKey }`

Answer (score 0):

Per TheIncorrigible's comment, try this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Method POST -Body $body -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer " + $API_key }
```

You are passing a JSON string, so you could also just use the ConvertTo-Json command to create your *true* API key. For info on that check this out: [using powershell with JSON data](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/using-powershell-with-json-data,1-3445.html)

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest : {"error":{"code":"UnsupportedMediaType","message":"Unsupported media type.","details":[{"code":"InvalidContentType","message":"The request entity's media type 
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is not supported for this resource."}]}}

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Method POST -Body $body -Headers @{ 'Content-Type' = 'application/json'; 'Authorization' = "Bearer " + $API_key }
```